# FB.Event.subscribe and login-button

Tags: facebook

On my page I have the FB login button code.  A user is able to join my site by authorizing it with Facebook, by pressing the FB login button.  My site lets users log out and many of them like to do that.

After I authorize my FB account for the site, log out of my site, I can't login any more because the session event never fires (unless I de-authorize it).  I press the FB Login button a white page opens, then closes right away, and nothing happens.  This seems to be because the FB session doesn't change (it already existed) so the event is never fired.  So I'm wondering if there's a way around this aside from hiding FB's login button and making my own if their session exists.  I tried "auth.login" but that doesn't fire either.

Button:

```
<fb:login-button perms="email,user_about_me,user_birthday">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

Event:

```
 FB.Event.subscribe('auth.sessionChange', function (response) {
                        document.location.href = "/FacebookLogin.aspx";
                    });
```

Steps to reproduce:

1. Click FB login and authorize app (in this case my site).  User is redirected to my FB login page and an account on my site is created.  The user is now logged into my site.
2. Logout of my site using my sites logout button
3. Click the FB login button to log back into site.  This is where the user should be redirected back to that same page from step 1 so they can be logged into the site.

All that happens in step 3 is a white page pops up for a couple seconds and then closes.  The site is already authorized and the session event isn't fired.

This also happens if I authorize with one browser and then go back with a different browser.  Just get the popup, it closes and nothing happens.  I must be missing something important.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem but, after a while, i solved it doing this:

```
function after_login_button(){
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if (response.status=="connected") {
            //User logged in! Do your code here
        }
    }, true);
}
```

You also need to call the onlogin event on the login-button:

```
<fb:login-button onlogin="after_login_button()" perms="email,user_about_me,user_birthday">Login with Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

This worked for me =).

PS - By the way, I'm using OAuth 2.0 and you should migrate your application to it too because in the developers zone, they say:
"Remember that all apps must migrate to OAuth 2.0 by October 1".

Sorry for eventual english errors =S

Comment: 'perms' should be 'scope' now. Everything else works fine for me.

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure that you are doing FB.Event.subscribe within

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
......
)};

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response){
.....
)};

};
```

I had the same problem. After I put it inside the fbAsyncInit, it started accepting the events "auth.login"..

Hope this will work for you.