# Facebook authentication login does not refresh page

Tags: javascript, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-authentication

I am using a mix of PHP SDK 3.x.x and Javascript SDK to log into Facebook authentication. When we click the login button the windows appears and after filling the credentials and submitting it does not refresh the page. The FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login') doesn't seem to trigger. What is the problem?

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
FB.init({
     appId   : '<?php echo $facebook->getAppId(); ?>',
     oauth  : true, // check login status
     cookie  : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
     xfbml   : true // parse XFBML
 });

// whenever the user logs in, we refresh the page
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
});

FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
    window.location.reload();
});


};

(function() {
 var e = document.createElement('script');
 e.src = document.location.protocol + '//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
 e.async = true;
 document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
}());
```

Comment: Are there any errors in the console?

Comment: nope. :( I thought there will be some js errors but nothing.

Comment: You can find solving this problem from here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7141762/fb-event-subscribe-and-login-button

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know, this log in procedure is handled using AJAX that's why the page is partially refreshed. I don't know what's the problem you are facing. In my solution I used this log in procedure at the first of the page and define variable and session based on fb $user and $user_profile. Later used this variables to update other part of the page.
As event is not triggered you should check the js and use fb example to understand how their sdk works
Hope this might help you.